# Allow user of R6 class to provide function which access `self`

Tags: r, rlang, r6

#### Goal

I want to tweak the following `R6` class such that `calc` is not hard coded but can be provided by the user.

#### Hard Coded

```r
library(R6)

A <- R6Class("A",
             public = list(
               run = function(x) {
                 private$calc(x)
               },
               result_codes = list(OK = 1, NOK = 2)
             ),
             private = list(
               calc = function(x) {
                 if (x >= 0) {
                   self$result_codes$OK
                 } else {
                   self$result_codes$NOK
                 }
               })
)
a <- A$new()
a$run(1)
# [1] 1
```

#### As a parameter

If I want the user to supply a custom `calc` function I could do the following:

```r
B <- R6Class("B",
             public = list(
               initialize = function(calc) {
                 private$calc <- calc
               },
               run = function(x) {
                 private$calc(x)
               },
               result_codes = list(OK = 1, NOK = 2)
             ),
             private = list(
               calc = NULL
             )
)
```

#### Problem

I want that the user can use  `self$result_codes`, but this does not work because the function is defined in the global environment where `self` is not known and not "within" the R6Class:

```r
b <- B$new(function(x) {
  print(rlang::env_parent())
  if (x >= 0) {
    self$result_codes$OK
  } else {
    self$result_codes$NOK
  }
})

b$run(1)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
#  Error in calc(...) : object 'self' not found
```

Thus, the user needs to provide `calc` like this:

```r
b <- B$new(function(x) {
  me <- environment(rlang::caller_fn())
  if (x >= 0) {
    me$self$result_codes$OK
  } else {
    me$self$result_codes$NOK
  }
})

b$run(-1)
# [2]
```

which I find cumbersome. Thus, I wrapped `calc` in `initialize`, such that the user can simply type `self$result_codes$OK` without bothering about changing the environment:

```r
B <- R6Class("B",
             public = list(
               initialize = function(calc) {
                 private$calc <- calc
                 environment(private$calc) <- self$.__enclos_env__
               },
               run = function(x) {
                 private$calc(x)
               },
               result_codes = list(OK = 1, NOK = 2)
             ),
             private = list(
               calc = NULL
             )
)

b <- B$new(function(x) {
  if (x >= 0) {
    self$result_codes$OK
  } else {
    self$result_codes$NOK
  }
})

b$run(-1)
# [1] 2
```

This feels extremely hackish, because I am using the internal environment `.__enclos_env__` (it seems like a road to hell to use double underscored properties).

How would I solve this problem? Is the approach of setting the environment of `private$calc` the right direction? If so, how to avoid using `.__enclos_env__`?

Comment: you can't use an `active` binding?

Comment: This would not resolve the scoping issue I guess? Problem boils down to: I define `calc` in the global environment, but I want it to access elements from **within** the `R6` class (whether `private`, `self` or `active` should not matter IMHO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward and fairly clean solution would be to pass `self` explicitly as a parameter to the `calc` callback:

```
B <- R6Class(
    "B",
    public = list(
        initialize = function(calc) {
            private$calc <- calc
        },
        run = function(x) {
            private$calc(self, x)
        },
        result_codes = list(OK = 1, NOK = 2)
    ),
    private = list(
        calc = NULL
    )
)

b <- B$new(function(self, x) {
    if (x >= 0) {
        self$result_codes$OK
    } else {
        self$result_codes$NOK
    }
})
```

Fiddling with environments (similarly to how you have attempted it) can work, but is a lot  more complex and makes the solution brittle.

Comment: Holy cow, so easy yet so elegant! Sometimes, one does not see the wood for the trees. Thanks.